# Using linestring in SQL Server Reporting Services maps

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, spatial, spatial-query

When creating SQL Server report with a map I am having difficulties using linestring.

To give some background I have several Routes that consist of several segments (linestrings) that data comes in multiple times an hour and it is desired to take the averages of some of that data for each segment.

Each data row has a code that corresponds to another table that has the segment detail in each row (code PK) including a the start Latitude and start Longitude and end lat and end longitude.

I have tried creating spatial columns for the start and end point and also line string but get errors or now map data in Reporting Service.

My queries will show the proper routes in SQL Management Studio but does not work in Reporting Services. Below is an example of one of the queries I have tried that the linestring does not work in

```
SELECT Geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING ('
                                 +CAST('41.783293' AS VARCHAR)
                                 +' '
                                 +CAST('-87.631526' AS VARCHAR)
                                 +', '
                                 +CAST('41.777581' AS VARCHAR)
                                 +' '
                                 +CAST('-87.630538' AS VARCHAR) 
                                 +')'     
                               ,4326) AS "Segment"
       ,RT1.Country
       ,RT1.State
       ,RT1.PostalCode
       ,IR.TimeMinutes
       ,IR.SegmentCongestionLevel
FROM Route RT1
  JOIN Raw IR
    ON RT1.S_Code = IR.Code
```

Example updated to include lat and long for one of the segments.  Please note that each Route/linestring will contain several (roughly 30-150) segments.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thanks.  Any thoughts on my actual question?

Comment: Can you add some Lat/Long data to your question that isn't working to see if we can replicate your issue?

Comment: done iamdave and thank you

Answer (score 0):

After much research there were errors latitude and longitude values that caused the Reporting Services maps not to line up with the linestrings.  Thank you all that reviewed